# Error 1040 too many connection mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

tengo un error 1040 *too many connection*. He visto que esto se puede solucionar aumentando la variable *max_connection*, pero esta variable no la puedo aumentar, el valor de esta variable es de **101** a que alternativa puedo recurrir para solucionar este error

Mi código para la conexión a la base de datos es la siguiente

```
<?php
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "grupomv");
$conexion->set_charset('utf8');
if($conexion->connect_errno) {
die ("Fallo al conectar a la BD: " . $conexion->connect_errno . "---" . $conexion->connect_error);
}
return $conexion;
?>
```

Y este es mi codigo que realiza la consulta a la base de Datos

```
<?php
           include"conexion.php";
           $stmt = $conexion->prepare("select * from bio, caract where caract.IDBio=bio.IDBio and idprod=? LIMIT 1");
           $stmt->bind_param("i", $prod);               
           $stmt->execute();
           $result=$stmt->get_result();
           $stmt->close();
           $conexion->close();
            while($data=$result->fetch_assoc()){

             // muestro los resultados

          }
            ?>
```

¿tengo algún problema en el código?

**Update**
Estas son los valores que poseen las variables del mysql, *estas variables no puedo modificarla ya que el hosting no me lo permite*

**max_user_connections** =35 
**max_connections** =101

Comment: el codigo esta bien intenta cambiar la variable de mysql esta en el my.ini max_user_connections  = 0 max_connection  = 0

Comment: @JackNavaRow mi problema radica en que no puedo modificar ninguna de las variables porque el hosting no me lo permite.
estas son los valores que tienen las variables en el mysql
**max_user_connections** =35
**max_connections** =101

Comment: Es la 1ª vez que veo un `return` fuera de una función y en verdad ignoro el efecto que eso pueda tener... sería interesante saberlo. Pero advierto de que es un código _loco_, del cual no tienes el control. Otra cosa sería que tuvieras el `return $conexion;` dentro de una clase o una función. Tal y como lo tienes ahora no tienes ningún control sobre tu objeto conexión. No se trata de aumentar el núm. de conexiones sino de optimizar. Te recomendaría usar una clase dedicada a gestionar las conexiones a la BD para evitar este tipo de problemas. Tengo una clase en Github por si te interesa.

Comment: @A.Cedano en estos momentos ando viendo la clase que me has comentado que posee en Github

Comment: Si tienes dudas puedes preguntarme. La Clase usa conexión persistente y hasta ahora no me ha dado problemas. De todos modos verás que, aunque no use conexiones persistentes, antes de crear un objeto conexión pregunta primero si no existe ya uno, lo cual impide que se creen conexiones innecesarias, aparte de que PDO suele cerrar la conexión cuando el script termina. Es una de sus ventajas, entre otras.

Comment: El return dentro de un include hace que se deje de ejecutar dicho include y se vuelva al hilo principal. No es muy normal, pero hay gente que por desgracia lo utiliza, de hecho está observado en la documentación. http://php.net/manual/es/function.return.php